# Repeating for loop in menu

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, menu

I'm trying to create a hotel menu in Java (I'm still learning the language) and I've run into an issue.  I can make the menu open a new menu, but when I make a choice from that second menu, it constantly loops.  I think it's the for loop that is causing the issue.  Can anyone advise how I get the second menu entry to stop looping?  Methods below:

Menu class method:

```
public void getMenu()
    {
        Floor floor = new Floor();


        Scanner kboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice = 0;

        System.out.println("Booking Menu");
        System.out.println("Select from the options below");
        System.out.println("1. Check room availability");
        System.out.println("2. Display floor");
        System.out.println("3. Display all availability");
        System.out.println("4. Cancel Booking");
        System.out.println("Please enter choice (press 8 to continue)");
        choice=kboard.nextInt();


        do
        {
            switch(choice)
            {
            case 1: room.getRoomMenu();
            break;
            case 2: 
            break;
            case 3: 
            break;
            }

        }
            while (choice !=8);
    }
```

That menu opens a second menu in this method:

```
    public void getRoomMenu()
    {
        Floor f1 = new Floor(1);
        Floor f2 = new Floor(2);
        Floor f3 = new Floor(3);
        Floor f4 = new Floor(4);
        boolean check = false;

        Scanner kboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice = 0;
        System.out.println("Which Floor?");
        System.out.println("1");
        System.out.println("2");
        System.out.println("3");
        System.out.println("4");
        choice=kboard.nextInt();
        do
        {
            switch(choice)
            {
            case 1: f1.displayFloor();
            break;
            case 2: f2.displayFloor();
            break;
            case 3: f3.displayFloor(); 
            break;
            case 4: f4.displayFloor(); 
            break;
            }
        }
        while(choice !=8);
        kboard.close();
    }
```

The second menu option should display the chosen floor which displays all rooms on that floor.  This is the displayFloor method:

```
public void displayFloor()
    {
        /**
         * Displays floor number and room display method
         */
        System.out.println("Floor: "+floorNumber);
            for(int counter=0;counter<rooms.length;counter++)
            {
                rooms[counter].display();
            }


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Both your while loops continue looping as long as `choice != 8`. And since you never modify the `choice` inside the loop, it will just continue looping (unless `8` was input by the user).

Also note that the `break;` you added are breaks for the `switch`-case, not to stop the `do-while`-loop. To have a `break` within the switch-case stop the entire `do-while`-loop, you should use a label to give the loop a name, and break that one. In addition, you should ask the user to give a new input if it didn't came into one of the switch-cases, otherwise it will still loop forever. So something like this:

```
choice = kboard.nextInt();
myLoop: do {
  switch(choice) {
    case 1:
      f1.displayFloor();
      break myLoop;
    case 2:
      f2.displayFloor();
      break myLoop;
    case 3:
      f3.displayFloor(); 
      break myLoop;
    case 4:
      f4.displayFloor(); 
      break myLoop;
    default: // Not one of the above
      System.out.println(choice + " is an unknown choice. Please choose again.");
      choice = kboard.nextInt(); // Ask the user for a new input
      break; // <- This break only breaks the switch, not the loop
  }
} while(choice !=8);
```

If your intention was to continue looping until the user input `8`, it should be something like this instead:

```
choice = kboard.nextInt();
do {
  switch(choice) {
    case 1:
      f1.displayFloor();
      break;
    case 2:
      f2.displayFloor();
      break;
    case 3:
      f3.displayFloor(); 
      break;
    case 4:
      f4.displayFloor(); 
      break;
    default: // Not one of the above
      System.out.println(choice + " is an unknown choice. Please choose again.");
  }
  choice = kboard.nextInt(); // Ask the user for a new input for the next iteration
} while(choice !=8);
```

Answer (score 0):

The loop is occurring here:

```
while(choice !=8);
```

You need to make sure that the ending condition is always satisfied at some point to avoid unwanted infinite loops.

Maybe you meant `if(choice != 8)` rather than a do/while loop (which will keep running until choice is 8, which will only occur if the user inputs 8).